# Como solucionar error Api.Exception: 12500 al iniciar sesión en Firebase con Google

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

Al crear la app con el inicio de sesión funciona correctamente si la app esta en debug pero al crear la app en release ya no.

El error que me aparece en la app es el siguiente:

[image: Error al iniciar sesión]

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

Estuve leyendo la documentacion con respecto al inicio de sesion con google y recomiendan utilizar *.requestScope* y no *.requestIdToken()*

```
 val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(Scope("******.apps.googleusercontent.com"))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

 firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
 googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
```

Asi lanzo el boton para iniciar sesion

```
 bt_sigin.setOnClickListener { startActivityForResult(Intent(googleSignInClient.signInIntent), 123) }
```

Obtener el resultado del intent

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 123) {

        val result = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)!!

        try {
            account = result.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)

        } catch (error: Exception) {
            Utils().mostrarToast(this, "Ocurrio un error -> $error")
        }
    }
}
```

Y así obtengo el idToken para crear la credencial y verificar en firebase

```
private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account: GoogleSignInAccount?) {

    bt_sigin.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    progress_login.visibility = View.VISIBLE

   // Log.i("prueba", "nombre ${account!!.displayName} \n id ${account.id} token ${account.idToken}")
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account!!.idToken, null)
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

        progress_login.visibility = View.GONE
        bt_sigin.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (task.isSuccessful) {

            firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!
            startActivity(Intent(this, Home::class.java)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
        } else {
            Utils().mostrarToast(this, "${getString(R.string.error_iniciar_sesion)} ${task.exception}")
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencias agregadas (Todas las de firebase)

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
```

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Estos son los proveedores de inicio de sesión que tengo activos en la consola de firebase

[image: Provedores firebase activos]

El *.requestScope* lo obtengo desde aquí (ID de cliente web)

[image: id de cliente web]

Creo que es todo lo requerido para utilizar el servicio de inicio de sesión con firebase, no se en que parte esta el error.

Gracias por la colaboración de antemano.

*Agrego la etiqueta java ya que si la solución esta en java también se programar en ese lenguaje*

Comment: Puede que sea alguna librería obsoleta o el plugin mismo de google services. Por ejemplo, ¿qué versión tienes en `classpath` del `gradle` de la carpeta del proyecto? La última es esta: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`

Comment: exactamente esa tengo, desistí de hacer la auth con firebase, simplemente deje la ahutenticacion con la cuenta de google y con el id de usuario manejo la base de datos. Gracias, nunca encontré el por que de este error en mi proyecto